# exchangelib: Sending an email as a distribution list

Tags: python, exchangelib

I'm using the exchangelib python EWS library to send emails. Sending from my mailbox works as expected but how can I send an email from a distribution list I have "Send As" permissions already applied (Have tested in Outlook changing the from address)?

The below code snippet will send the email but "me@domain.com" account shows as the sender. If I change "access_type=DELEGATE" to "access_type=IMPERSONATION", I receive an error "ErrorNonExistentMailbox: The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.".

```
credentials = Credentials("me@domain.com", password)
config = Configuration(server=server, credentials=credentials)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address="distlist@domain.com", config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)

message = Message(account=account,subject="subject",folder=None)
message.sender = "distlist@domain.com"
message.to_recipients = "me@domain.com"
message.body = "test"
message.send(save_copy=False, copy_to_folder=False)
```

Any help or guidance is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distribution list usually doesn't have its own mailbox in Exchange, so you can't use its email address as `primary_smtp_address` for the account.

Messages have both a `sender` and an `author` field. You could try to set the distribution list email in the `author` field. Then emails may show up as coming from that email address.

Comment: Thanks Erik - That worked! Looks like I was over complicating it. Thank you again!